# issue in debugging code for class

Tags: java, debugging

so i'm doing a project for my Computer Science class where i'm building a wheel of fortune game, and for some reason im having an error with debugging my code. if anyone can help, id be very greatful.
** full code in comments wont let me post it ***

```
public class WheelOfFortune {
    private String Hidden;
    public WheelOfFortune(String g) {
        Hidden = g;
    }
    public String getHint(String g) {
        String letter, HL, result = "";
        int x = g.length(), y = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            letter = g.substring(i, i + 1);
            HL = Hidden.substring(i, i + 1);
            if (letter.equals(HL)) {
                result += letter;
                y = Hidden.indexOf(letter);
            }
            if (y == -1) result = "*";
            else result = "+";
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Puzzle {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WheelOfFortune guess = new WheelOfFortune("HARPS");
        String turn = guess.getHint("AAAAA");
        System.out.println(turn);
    }
}
```

Comment: public class WheelOfFortune 
{
 private String Hidden;
 public WheelOfFortune(String g)
 {
  Hidden = g;
 }
 
 public String getHint(String g)
 {
  String letter, HL, result = "" ;
  int x = g.length(), y = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i< x ; i++)
  {
   letter = g.substring(i, i +1);
   HL= Hidden.substring(i, i+ 1);
   if (letter.equals(HL))
   {
    result += letter;
   y = Hidden.indexOf(letter);
   }
  
   if ( y == -1)
   
    result = "*";
   
   else  
    result = "+";
   return result;
  }
  }
 }

Comment: public class Puzzle 
{
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  WheelOfFortune guess = new WheelOfFortune ("HARPS");
  String turn = guess.getHint("AAAAA");
  System.out.println(turn);
 }
}

Comment: Edit ur question ,add ur above codes(mentioned in commend)  also in ur question also mention the language in tag

Comment: oh sorry for not including that yes it is

Comment: but im still having issues figuring out my error

Comment: Without editing your code its very difficult to answer ur problem

Comment: you can edit my code. or at least i think you can.

Comment: also to get a better sense of what im trying to do ill include the guidelines in the next comment

Comment: Consider a guessing game in which a player tries to guess a hidden word.  The hidden word contains only capital letters and has a length known only to the player.  A guess contains only capital letters and has the same length as the hidden word.

After a guess is made, the player is given a hint that is based on a comparison between the hidden word and the guess.  Each position in the hint contains a character that corresponds to the letter in the same position in the guess.   The following rules determine the characters that appear in the hint.

Comment: If the letter in the guess is… The corresponding character in the hint is
Also in the same position in the hidden word,  The matching letter
Also in the hidden word, but in a different position, “+”
Not in the hidden word, “*”

The WheelofFortune class will be used to represent the hidden word in the game.  The hidden word is passed to the constructor.  The class contains a method called getHint, that takes a guess and produces a hint. 
 
For example, suppose the variable guess is declared as follows:

WheelofFortune  guess = new WheelofFortune(“HARPS”);

Comment: The following table shows several guesses and the hints that would be produced

Call to getHint String returned
guess.getHint(“AAAAA”) “+A+++”
guess.getHint(“HELLO”) “H****”
guess.getHint(“HEART”) “H*++*”
guess.getHint(“HARMS”) “HAR*S”
guess.getHint(“HARPS”)  “HARPS”

Write the complete WheelofFortune class, including any necessary instance variables, its constructor, and the method getHint, described above.  Assume that the length of the guess is the same as the length of the hidden word.

Comment: Test the program with the example above.

Also test the program with a hidden word of STEAM

Use the guess, STORE (returned “ST**+”)
Use the guess, HAPPY (returned “*+***”
Use the guess, ROPES (returned “***++”)

Comment: allllsssooooo thank you for helping at all

Comment: i had implemented you code and i am getting a few bugs in addition

Answer (score 0):

Your code didn't even compile because of a *missing return statement* after the `for` loop. With this and other errors corrected, your `getHint()` is:

```
    public String getHint(String g)
    {
        String letter, HL, result = "";
        int x = g.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
        {
            letter =  g.substring(i, i + 1);
            HL = Hidden.substring(i, i + 1);
            if (letter.equals(HL))       result += letter;
            else
            if (Hidden.contains(letter)) result += "+";
            else
                                         result += "*";
        }
        return result;
    }
```